# How can I delete a snippet in Visual Studio C# Express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-express, code-snippets

I've added a number of snippets in Visual Studio C# Express.

Many are in the list double and I want to delete them.

When the cursor is on the FOLDER called "MySnippets" the delete button is active.

But when the **cursor is on an individual snippet, the delete button is grayed out**.

I assume this is a bug, so are snippets saved in **an XML file somewhere so that I can just edit them manually?**

Comment: in VS 2012 Express, the manager is built in so you can add, delete, import etc from VS itself

Answer (score 3):

There should be a Visual Studio folder in your documents folder, Snippets are below that.

Comment: I deleted the "My Snippets" folder and although it exists in that folder it's not showing up, looking for some meta file somewhere, e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\SnippetsIndex.xml but that doesn't reflect what is in menu under CTRL-K, B.

Answer (score 2):

here is the easiest way I found to manage snippets:

1. put all your snippet files in one directory somewhere.
2. press CTRL-K, B, and then the "Add.." button to add that directory.
3. then any changes you make to your snippets will be instantly reflected.
4. don't use the "Import..." button.